# 'adb command not found, review your android sdk Installation" error In Android studio Wifi ADB Plugin

Tags: android

Recenlty I found a Android Studio Plugin which help to convert usb adb to wifi adb. But after following all the instruction I am getting 'adb command not found, review your android sdk Installation" error. What's my problem?

Plugin GitHub link: https://github.com/pedrovgs/AndroidWiFiADB

Comment: i am also just tried it, and facing the same problem!

Comment: Wait for the update..

https://github.com/pedrovgs/AndroidWiFiADB/issues/13?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container

Comment: same issue i am facing

Comment: Meanwhile, you can try this one. It helps connect to wifi adb instead. 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobisci_lab.icable

Answer (score 26, accepted):

if you are using mac paste this code in terminal and change USER_NAME

```
export PATH=/Users/USER_NAME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```

Comment: And need to run source ~/.bash_profile again to make it works.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the platform-tools path to your system environment variable and then restart the terminal or command prompt.

For example if you are using Windows 10, you will find the platform-tools in AppData folder.

e.g. : **C:\Users\tarunsmalviya12\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools**

Answer (score -1):

You can add the Adb.exe file path from your SDK to PATH variable in system environment variable.
Restart Android studio.

To cross check if the path is properly set you can open command prompt and execute adb command.

If it works fine your android studio will.